# Enable scroll in table-cell displayed and centered div

Tags: html, css

How do I enable scroll on the centered div? the height is dinamic so I can't really declare it.

The code is below, and in some cases may don't need to scroll as the content  wouldn't be enough to require it.

The div must be centered both vertically (when it's height is less than the viewport height) and horizontally.

```css
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
}
.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.modal-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-mask">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-container">
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>         
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My other solution was:

```css
.modal-mask {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.modal-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-mask">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-container">
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>         
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
     This needs scroll<br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem with this is that the container doesn't get vertically centered when the height is lower than the viewport

Comment: @VXp Like a normal page/body, when needed the scroll is enable: https://jsfiddle.net/bda7ureq/ , the problem with this solution is that the container doesn't get centered when height is less than the viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the below code. Hope it may help you

```
.modal-container {overflow-y: auto; max-height: 100vh;}
```

Comment: Yap, I seems that just `max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;` did the trick, thank you, maybe you should edit the anwser to include only that, (or `max-height: 100vh`), as the other stuff are not relevant to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: @HulaHula I really don't know how this solves the problem.

Comment: @VXp, https://jsfiddle.net/bda7ureq/1/ . You can erase the `overflow-y` and `max-height` from the css to see what happens

Comment: @HulaHula This is not what you wrote in the description.

Comment: @VXp, what did I write wrong? I think I was very clear that I wanted the modal (container) to have scroll when necessary

Comment: @HulaHula Applying `max-height: 100vh` doesn't make it vertically centered and also its `height` isn't dynamic, it just makes it responsive, but the height is static, which is `100vh`.

Comment: @VXp, nop it's `max-height` is 100vh not it's height: https://jsfiddle.net/bda7ureq/2/ , has you can see it's height it's not 100vh (it's dinamic) and it's centered. Yap, just with these two css properties

Comment: @HulaHula I mean the max-height is static, then your post information about what you'd like to achieve is wrong, because this solution doesn't do that, the only thing it does is that it enables scrolling.

Comment: @VXp, how is it wrong the title itself says that I want to "enable scroll..." That's what this does, you said it yourself "the only thing it does is that it enables scrolling". What did you think I wanted to achieve? Where am I not being clear about this?